# Codeigniter Undefined property: xxxx_model::$db only from Model

Tags: database, codeigniter, view

First the Model class:

```
    class Xxxx_model extends Model
    {
      function XxxxModel()
      {
        parent::Model();
        $this->load->database();
      }

      function isInDatabase()
      {
        // Please ignore the sql query, it's just to show some random sql code with results
11.      $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ...');
        $numberOfRows = $result->num_rows();
        ... 
        return $test;
      }
    }
```

Now the controller:

```
function someLogic()
{
  $this->load->model('xxxx_Model', 'xxxxModel'); // not necessary to specify
  $this->xxxxModel->isInDatabase();
}
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
Severity: Notice  --> Undefined property: Xxxx_model::$db .../xxxx_model.php line 11
```

I have no idea why this is. If I put the db code in the controller it seems to work, it's only with this setup in the model that it fails. I can't for the life of me figure out where the code is astray...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to atno's answer:

```
class Xxxx_model extends Model
{
  function XxxxModel() //<--- does not match model name Xxxx_model
  {
    parent::Model();
    $this->load->database();
  }
```

Basically, you are not constructing the class ***or*** the parent class `Model`. If you are on PHP5, you may use `__construct()`, otherwise you must match the class name exactly, regardless of what alias you load it with in your controller. Example:

```
class Xxxx_model extends Model
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(); // construct the Model class
  }
}
```

I may be mistaken (haven't used 1.x in a while), but if you construct the Model class, there's no need to load the database if you are using the default connection settings in `config/database.php`, it should already be loaded for you.

Comment: In fact, loading the database is definitely not needed if `$this->db` was available and working in the controller as mentioned, without having it loaded by the model as expected.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the constructor name! That's brutal. I've been on a 36+ hour coding spree because of a timeline. That's definitely one of the issues. I had to change the name of the model for it to be correctly loaded according to the docs, where I guess I missed also refactoring the name of the constructor.

Comment: Btw, if I adjust the name of the constructor, I don't have to autoload the database anymore. Yeah :)

Comment: @StephaneGrenier: Turn on some death metal and make some coffee to wake you up :) Also, definitely worth checking out the current 2.x some day, it's a very simple upgrade process and the docs are a bit better as well.

Comment: I was considering it, but I was also on a very tight deadline and just couldn't afford the time to upgrade. I will be looking into it shortly, see what's new and exciting other than just a version number increase ;) It's an awesome framework that's for sure.

Comment: Aside, I don't recall ever having to construct the Model class in a CI Model... The 2.0 is not exciting really, but the huge thing for me was being able to use `$_GET`

Answer (score 12):

You have to load the db library first. In `autoload.php` add below code,

```
$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```

Comment: The person who asked the question has already used  $this->load->database(); . So autoload is not required in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

add library 'datatabase' to autoload.

/application/config/autoload.php

`$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'database'
);`

Propably you're started new project, like me ;-)

Comment: Just perfect!  I was starting a new project

Answer (score 2):

If `function XxxxModel()` isn't your constructor, you're not loading the database by calling `$this->xxxxModel->isInDatabase();`

Try autoloading the database library from within `autoload.php`, or create a proper constructor in your model.

Comment: He would have had different errors if this was the case (i.e. class Model not found), but otherwise you are correct.

Comment: +1 to your edit - good catch. I'm sure OP will come back and claim it was a typo, I don't see the reason to hide the model name, Xxxxx is barely readable.

Comment: Isn't there a performance cost to autoloading it for each url if I only need it in a few places? Btw, that did solve it.

Comment: Yes there is a tiny performance hit if you don't need database connection on every page. If you just need it only if you places you can create a `MY_DB_Model` class that will extend `Model` and include the database loading. Every time you need to fetch data from your DB extend that model, else CI's `Model`. Please mark the correct answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier: If `$this->db` was working in your controller but the model was broken, you already had the database loaded...

Comment: I struggled on who to give the checkmark to because both worked, but the controller constructor name is why it wasn't working, the database autoload fixes it, but it's more of a workaround than the perfect solution. It's also more generic whereas the other one is more specific to this problem. Tough call...